# Are there other ways to put an Automotive media app onto the car without Google Play (polestar 2 API level 28 issue)

Tags: android-automotive

I have built a media app and it works great in the emulator.
As I actually own a Polestar 2 vehicle, I am running the Polestar 2 image (API Level 28 - Android 9)
But when I want to release the app to the play store (even as private test) then the store requires a minimum version of API Level 29.

I appreciate Polestar will need to update their image to Android 10 (or maybe even 11 already) before I can release my app through the Play store, but is there any other way to get the app on the car?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on the Polestar forum:

- Min / Target versions (28 and 29)
- Created Closed test track

https://www.polestar-forum.com/threads/android-os-simulator.517/post-22804